# Error handling for ajax file uploading with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, file-upload

With CodeIgniter 2.1.4 I'm trying to upload a file using ajax and the File Uploading Class. I have the construct in the Controller as:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
}
```

And my upload function in the Controller as:

```
public function upload_file()
{

    $config['upload_path'] = 'upload/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $result['success'] = 1;
        $result['message'] = $error;
    }
    else
    {
        $result['success'] = 0;
        $result['message'] = "Successful Upload";
    }

    die(json_encode($result));

}
```

But the errors are coming out as:

```
Array
```

How can I get the error message out of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line and try:

```
$result['message'] = $error['error'];
```

Answer (score 0):

When error has occurred your result is a array. You used json encode in die function.

Don't encode in die function.

```
echo json_encode($result);
die();
```

Comment: I'm not aware this makes any difference at all

Comment: I dont no what the issue. did u use print_r for get the issue? Use file field name with upload function. it is should the issue.